# How to change the action bar menu icon when the Drawer is in open mode by click on ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Please find the below screenshots and code, i want to change "menu" icon to "close" icon when Menu is Open mode.

When we click on Menu icon in Screen1, we want to show the screen with "close" icon at top left, but it is not working. How can i achieve this?

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final CharSequence mTitle) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

//      actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        final TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);

        mTitleTextView.setText(mTitle);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP );
        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, params);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.menu_icon, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.hello_world,
        R.string.hello_world ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                mTitleTextView.setText("");
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
        // them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem...do you know the answer¿? I don't want to use a custom actionBar xml ...

Comment: @KryNaC: i don't know the answer, we used default one.

Comment: Then, do you have the same icon with NavigationDrawer opened and closed¿?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom action bar xml then add it like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

Then set an onClickListener which toggles either the image drawable, or perhaps the state using a selector drawable:

```
//Use a custom menu button
findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_menu_selected));
        }else{
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            //Could either set the image drawable
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_menu));
            //Or set the image src to a drawable and just change the state:
            //findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button).setSelected(true);
        }
    }
});
```